# need a method to return the value of a specific bit of an int

Tags: java

I think I need a utility method like this:

```
public static short bitValue(int intNum, short pos)
{
    short bitValue = 0;

    //check pos bit (from right to left) in the intNum integer to see its value is 0 or 1
    //And then update the bitValue for return

    return bitValue;
}
```

I am doing research to learn how to do it now. If anyone of you guy have code in hand, please share with me. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a shift and mask:

```
return (short) ((intNum >> pos) & 1);
```

That's assuming you want a return value of 1 or 0, of course. If you want bit itself, still with the same value, you'll need to change your return type to `int` and use:

```
return intNum & (1 << intNum);
```

Comment: I only want to know the value of that bit specified by the pos parameter. thanks. I need to review those shift operators now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than a word's worth of bits to deal with, consider using BitSet.